# jQuery: shortening $(this).find('.something').xxx into $(this, '.something').xxx

Tags: jquery-selectors

Can I, in jQuery, combine $(this) with another element selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's:

```
$('.something', this)
```

They're equivalent, since this functionality (selector context) is actually implemented using `find`.  There's a similar example in [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/):

> $('span', this) is equivalent to
>   $(this).find('span').